# Help needed to Identify Japanese font

Tags: fonts, font-identification, japanese

It's from a Casio electronic toy from the mid-nineties and I've been searching everywhere without any luck. If anyone has an idea of the name or why I can find it I'd be very grateful! Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Try using [LikeFont](https://en.likefont.com/) - it's a website for identifying Japanese/Chinese fonts.

Comment: You may have to edit the image to use it with likefont's automated seach, remove the background and strokes around the letters, or clean it up a bit, etc.  There's also a Community/forum linked to likefont where you can ask humans to identify it for you.